# How to get Array Items inside of List<object> c#

Tags: c#, arraylist, ienumerable

How to get Array Items inside of List c#

```
IEnumerable<object> enumerable = c1._getbrandrequest(object[]);

List<object> brand = enumerable.Cast<object>().ToList();

List<Brand> brands = new List<Brand>();

for (int i = 0; i <= enumerable.Count(); i++)
{

    var brnd = enumerable.ElementAt(i);

    // brnd (intellisense only produce)
    // brnd. { Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, ToString }

}
```

[Image of ArrayItems from Web Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6s5g.jpg)

thanks in Advance!

Comment: It's a list of `object`s so you have to cast it to the right type, which I am guessing is `object[]`.

Comment: You should cast the generic object to the actual type it is for intellisense to work. One option is you can debug and check what type it is in the runtime.

Comment: In my Object Array

{ [0] - { reqid = "1", sid = "2" } }
{ [1] - { reqid = "1", sid = "2" } }

this is the screenshot

http://s11.postimg.org/tffcvvtzn/help2.jpg

Answer (score 1):

If `enumerable` contains `Brand` objects, then what you need is cast the element returned by `enumerable.ElementAt(i)`:

```
var brnd = enumerable.ElementAt(i) as Brand;
```

Comment: Hello Aruto, brnd return Null.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code can be a bit cleaner in this way:

```
IEnumerable<object> enumerable = c1._getbrandrequest(object[]);
List<Brand> brands = enumerable.OfType<Brand>().ToList();

foreach (Brand brnd in brands)
{
  // Do things with brnd.
}
```

The OfType only returns objects that have a runtime type Brand, and the result is an IEnumerable, the ToList() makes them into a fresh list.

Comment: Hello Evert, brands return 0.

Comment: Ah, the enumerable is a bunch of Request objects. I don't have enough information to help you further, e.g. how to get a Brand based on a request, I assume you have to perform the request in some way?

Answer (score 0):

```
        var enumerable = c1._getbrandrequest( Object[] );

        List<Brand> brands = new List<Brand>();

        foreach (var brnd in enumerable)
        {
            Brand model = new Brand();

            model.sid = brnd.sid;

            brands.Add(model);

        }
```